# How to show content of method inside another method?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to split one method to many little methods, but I want my code to still be simple to read. Is it possible to display content of methods in place, the way it was before the split? I want to display them in the same way explorer displays folders: you see files and folders, click on the triangle left to a folder to show what's inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. However you can use the "Peek Definition" feature of Visual Studio (since VS 2013, not in Express Versions however).

If you have your newly refactored method like:

```
public void RefactoredMethod()
{
   DoStuff();
   SomeMore();
   Validate();
   Save();
}
```

you can right-click any of the smaller methods and choose "Peek Definition" to show the method inline at the current place. You can also bind it to a shortcut.

Comment: Yes I can, but it will cost me one year of my life. Thank you.